# How to get ToolTip binding to work with a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

Currently I have a ComboBox defined as:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumDataItems}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
            ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}" // never displays the value
            SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value}" />
```

Everything works except the ToolTip. The property that it should bind to; `ToolTip` *does* contain a value. I'm sure of this because when I do the following, I see a result confirming that ToolTip contains a value:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumDataItems}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="ToolTip" // I replaced 'Description' with 'ToolTip'
            ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"
            SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
```

Having replaced `Description` with `ToolTip` I can see that the value of ToolTip is appearing on the screen. However

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"
```

still doesn't work. If I attempt to display ToolTip as follows:

```
ToolTip="ToolTip"
```

it just displays the word 'ToolTip'.

How can I get `ToolTip` to display a value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"` binds to `ToolTip` property of current combo box `DataContext` (object that contains `EnumDataItems` property).
Assuming you want to set `ToolTip` of `ComboBox` to currently selected item's `ToolTip` property value, this should fix the problem:

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Answer (score 41):

If a `ToolTip` for every `ComboBoxItem` is what you want you can do this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this - this was the next step I was getting to. As the other answer answered the asked question I accepted that as the correct one, but I found this extremely useful so thank you.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Very simple and effective. I saw this horror sample and I knew that it must be a simpler way. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/52ee62b4-41b6-44c1-8d2d-0243162266ef/