# How to binding combobox to tooltip wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem when trying binding from combobox to tooltip. I want to bind SelectedValue to tooltip and add a string before SelectedValue on tooltip.
EX: SelectedValue: ID_001. Tooltip = Your ID: ID_001.
My xaml:

```
<ComboBox ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=cbb_ma_kh, Path=SelectedValue}"  
          Height="32" 
          Margin="115,39,24,0" 
          Name="cbb_ma_kh" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ToolTip binding to work with a ComboBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259479/how-to-get-tooltip-binding-to-work-with-a-combobox)

Comment: It's not answer i looking for

Comment: Are you using an ItemsSource? If yes, if it is a complex object, you probably should specify the SelectedValuePath. For attaching a string to the selected value of the combo and binding it to the tooltip, you could use a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the simplest solution would be a Converter to prepend the text.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Ids}"
    ToolTip="{Binding SelectedValue, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                      Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}}"         
    ...
    >
```

Building the string in XAML is a bit trickier. ElementName and RelativeSource no longer work once you get inside the `<ComboBox.ToolTip> ... </ComboBox.ToolTip>`. So you would have to bind the SelectedValue to your DataContext to access it later on.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Ids}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedIdValue}"
    ...
    >
    <ComboBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip 
            Content="{Binding SelectedIdValue}"
            ContentStringFormat="Your ID: {0}"
            />
    </ComboBox.ToolTip>
</ComboBox>
```