# WPF DataTemplate Tooltip not displaying properly

Tags: wpf, combobox, tooltip

I have a couple Comboboxes which use a DataTemplate and I am not able to set a Tooltip inside the DataTemplate to display. The DataTemplate utilizes a Textblock with a couple of `<Run>`'s. The Textblock inside the DataTemplate displays the data data properly except for the Tooltip (nothing pops up).

If I add the Tooltip directly to the Combobox it works but I do not want to do this because I would have to add the Tooltip to each Combobox that uses that DataTemplate.

Here is my ComboBox code

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=HeaderRecord.Item}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
```

Here is my Data Template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" DataType="models:Item">
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
               TextWrapping="NoWrap"
               ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=ItemNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Run Text=": " />
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ToolTip binding to work with a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259479/how-to-get-tooltip-binding-to-work-with-a-combobox)

Comment: No this is a different issue. That question is regarding binding a ToolTip directly to a ComboBox. Per my description, I can do that but I want to bind the ToolTip to the DataTemplate instead. That way I only bind it once instead of evertime a ComboBox uses that template.

Comment: See **second answer** to the linked question.

Comment: There are several different WPF pages that utilize the DataTemplate and each page can have multiple ComboBoxes on them which are bound to different Elements/DataTemplates. So I do not believe that will work either.

Comment: Your Tooltip should be displayed. I cannot reproduce your issue. What if you temporarily set the Tooltip property of the TextBlock to a constant value like "test"? Which version of the .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: Is the problem that you can't get a tooltip in the item template to display for the selected item when the combobox is closed?

Comment: No the issue is when I hover over the Combobox after selecting an Item inside it the Tooltip does not display. I have tested taking off the binding and just having  "Testing" as the Tooltip but that will not display either (before or after selecting an item in the Combobox).